# API call to display json data

Tags: php

have a API call that gets JSON data with the following headers and info, need the php code that would display the below data in a table format:

the API call is: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/service/price/all?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

any help? I am a beginner.

[{"SKU":"CGP-15-GR-2017","Name":"2017 15 Grams Chinese Gold Panda Coin 200 Yuan BU Sealed","Metal":"Gold","ProductFamily":"Current Year Gold Coins","AssetClass":"Gold Bullion","Ounces":0.482315112540193,"Cogs":962.25,"Bid":907.52,"Ask":1042.34,"BaseCurrency":"USD","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"25-OZ-ATB-SET-2010","Name":"2010 America the Beautiful 5 oz Silver Bullion Coin Set","Metal":"Silver","ProductFamily":"ATB Bullion Program","AssetClass":"Silver Bullion","Ounces":25.0,"Cogs":779.16,"Bid":574.16,"Ask":1330.33,"BaseCurrency":"USD","Description":"25-OZ-ATB-SET-2010","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"PS-1-GR-PLAT-BAR","Name":"1 Gram Pamp Suisse Platinum Bar 999 Fine With Assay","Metal":"Platinum","ProductFamily":"Platinum Bullion","AssetClass":"Platinum","Ounces":0.03215,"Cogs":34.92,"Bid":27.6,"Ask":48.8,"BaseCurrency":"USD","Description":"1-PS-1-GR-PLAT-BAR","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"40-WQ-ROLL-BU","Name":"$10 Washington Quarters - 90% Silver 40-Coin Roll (BU)","Metal":"Silver","ProductFamily":"90% Junk Silver","AssetClass":"Silver Bullion","Ounces":7.15,"Cogs":165.64,"Bid":164.21,"Ask":234.67,"BaseCurrency":"USD","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"GIH-$10-NGCMS64-1932","Name":"GIH-$10-NGCMS64-1932","Metal":"Gold","ProductFamily":"Current Year Gold Coins","AssetClass":"Gold Bullion","Ounces":0.5,"Cogs":943.3,"Bid":990.8,"Ask":1865.03,"BaseCurrency":"USD","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"CGP-10th-2012","Name":"2012 1/10 oz Chinese Gold Panda Coin BU Sealed","Metal":"Gold","ProductFamily":"Current Year Gold Coins","AssetClass":"Gold Bullion","Ounces":0.1,"Cogs":222.62,"Bid":188.16,"Ask":387.52,"BaseCurrency":"USD","Description":"CGP-10th-2012","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"5-OZ-ATB--MBRNP-2020","Name":"2020 5 oz Silver ATB Marsh-Billings-Rockefeller National Park","Metal":"Silver","ProductFamily":"ATB Bullion Program","AssetClass":"Silver Bullion","Ounces":5.0,"Cogs":135.83,"Bid":114.83,"Ask":156.87,"BaseCurrency":"USD","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"SAK-Tenth-NGCPF69-2008","Name":"2008 South Africa 1/10 oz Gold Proof Krugerrand  NGC PF 69 DCAM","Metal":"Gold","ProductFamily":"Current Year Gold Coins","AssetClass":"Gold Bullion","Ounces":0.1,"Cogs":188.66,"Bid":188.16,"Ask":279.41,"BaseCurrency":"USD","Description":"SAK-OUNCE-1977","RetailShipping":0.0,"WholesaleShipping":0.0},{"SKU":"1-OUNCE-AGE-1987","Name":"1987 1 oz Gold American Eagle Coin Brand New BU","Metal":"Gold","ProductFamily":"Current Year Gold Coins","AssetClass":"Gold

Comment: add start line of php file  ```  header('Content-type:application/json'); ```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JSON data into an array and then iterate it with a `foreach()`

```
$arr = json_decode(JSON_DATA_FROM_API);//The data from your api
<table>
    <tr>
         <th scope="col">COL1</th>
         <th scope="col">COL2</th>
         <th scope="col">COL3</th>
         <th scope="col">COl4</th>
    </tr>
foreach($arr as $item) {
    <tr>
        <td>$item['SKU']</td>
        <td>$item['Name']</td>
        <td>$item['Metal']</td>
        <td>$item['ProductFamily']</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it but getting a syntax error - can you please give me the exact code syntax like the opeing and closing tags etc.

Comment: All tags are present here, the opening and closing ones.